How to send ETH in a titanoboa transaction
Let's say I want to call the deposit function on a WETH contract. This function takes no parameters, but I can add ETH to it.
Using titanoboa, how would I send ETH with the transaction?
Something like:
weth.deposit(value = 7)


You'd do as your example shows. The value is a keyword argument in a titanoboa transaction.
weth.deposit(value = 7)

